# P4 GREP - how to search for specific files by content in all subdirs

Tags: perforce

How to search for a file matching pattern  in depot, containing specific string, search should be in all sub directories using console `P4 grep`

lets say the depot looks like this:

```
//My-Depot/Ver10/javas/foo
//My-Depot/Ver10/javas/foo/inetrface
//My-Depot/Ver10/javas/foo/implementation
//My-Depot/Ver10/javas/boo
//My-Depot/Ver10/javas/coo
```

all  folders have java files, I want to search for java files containing word 'byte' in

```
//My-Depot/Ver10/javas/foo
```

and all subdirs.

I tried the following

```
p4 grep  -n -e "byte" //My-Depot/Ver10/javas/foo/.../*.java
```

This searches for *.java with word 'byte' in all sub directories of 'foo' but NOT for files that located directly under 'foo'

```
 p4 grep  -n -e "byte" //My-Depot/Ver10/javas/foo/*.java
```

This searches for *.java with word 'byte'  located directly under 'foo' but not the sub directories.

And I can't search in parent directory

```
 p4 grep  -n -e "byte" //My-Depot/Ver10/javas/.../*.java
```

Because it will search where I don't need it ti search (under 'boo' and 'coo').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
p4 grep  -n -e "byte" //My-Depot/Ver10/javas/foo/.../*.java //My-Depot/Ver10/javas/foo/*.java
```

...will get you what you want.

Comment: PS. I highly recommend taking the time to install P4Search. It is 1000x worth the effort of installing it.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `...` not followed by a slash, since you don't mean to *require* a nested subdirectory:

`p4 grep  -n -e "byte" //My-Depot/Ver10/javas/foo/....java`